# XML tags&attributes to HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I have an XML file with some data in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dinosaurs.xslt"?>
<dinolist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
   dinosaurs.xsd">
   <dinosaur period="Late Cretaceous">
      <name>Tyrannosaurus</name>
      <group>Carnosaur</group>
      <range>
         <region>Europe</region>
         <region>North America</region>       
      </range>
      <physio>
         <length unit = "feet">36</length>
         <weight unit = "tons">6</weight>
         <diet>carnivorous </diet>       
      </physio>
   </dinosaur>
   <dinosaur period="Late Jurassic">
      <name>Stegosaurus</name>
      <group>Stegosaur</group>
      <range>
         <region>Europe</region>
         <region>Asia</region>
         <region>North America</region>       
      </range>
      <physio>
         <length unit = "metres">9</length>
         <weight unit = "kgs">3100</weight>
         <diet>herbivorous</diet>        
      </physio>
   </dinosaur>
    <dinosaur period="Late Triassic">
      <name>Coelophysis</name>
      <group>Theropod</group>
      <range>
         <region>Africa</region>
         <region>North America</region>       
      </range>
      <physio>
         <length unit = "feet">6</length>
         <weight unit = "kgs">27</weight>
         <diet>carnivorous </diet>       
      </physio>
   </dinosaur>
   <dinosaur period="Late Jurassic">
      <name>Diplodocus</name>
      <group>Sauropod</group>
      <range>
         <region>North America</region>       
      </range>
      <physio>
         <length unit = "metres">26</length>
         <weight unit = "tons">20</weight>
         <diet>herbivorous</diet>        
      </physio>
   </dinosaur>
   <dinosaur period="Late Cretaceous">
      <name>Triceratops</name>
      <group>Ceratopsian</group>
      <range>
         <region>North America</region>       
      </range>
      <physio>
         <length unit = "metres">9</length>
         <weight unit = "tons">5.5</weight>
         <diet>herbivorous</diet>        
      </physio>
   </dinosaur>
</dinolist>
```

I want to present it like a table in HTML. Here is my XSLT file where I try to give the XML file proper view. It must guarantee the proper view of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:template match = "dinolist">
        <html><head><title>Dinosaurs</title></head>
        <body><h1>Dinosaurs</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "dinosaur"/>
        </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "dinosaur">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
        <table border ="1" width = "400" cellpadding = "5">
        <tr>
            <th>Period</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@period"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Group</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="group"/></td>
        </tr>       
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "range/"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "physio/"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "range">
        <tr>
            <th>Range</th>
            <td>
            <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="region">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "physio">
        <xls:if test ="length">
            <tr>
            <th>Length</th>
            <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="length"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping = "yes">
            &amp;nbsp;
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="length/@unit"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </xls:if>
        <xls:if test ="weight">
            <tr>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="weight"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping = "yes">
            &amp;nbsp;
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="weight/@unit"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </xls:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't work and I can see only the empty page.
What's the problem? Can you recommend something that'll help?

Comment: Check the browser's error console F12

Comment: In general, if you want a browser to load XML and apply referenced XSLT make sure you load over HTTP(S) and not from the file system. And I would recommend to develop and test first outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos where instead of the prefix `xsl` you have used `xls` e.g. `<xls:if test ="weight">` needs to be changed to `<xsl:if test ="weight">`.

And path expressions don't end with a slash so instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select = "range/"/>` you probably want `<xsl:apply-templates select = "range"/>`. The same problem exists in another line.